# Linked-list in linked-lists in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I ran in soms trouble using a list of lists. I'm using a singly linked-list, the linked-list consists of 3 classes (Node, ListIterator and List) these are template classes.
The linked-list is tested for every type. Class List and other classes are using operator<< to avoid print functions.

I've written some pseudocode to show my problem, the ?? indicate the problem area:

```
    class First
    { private:
    string name;    
    public:
        Tentamen (string n) : naam(n) {}
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const First& f)
        { return out << "First: " << f.name << endl; }
    };

    class Second
    { private:
        string name;
        List<First> l1;
    public:
        Second(string n) : naam(n){}
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Second& s)
        {
           out << "Second: " << s.name << endl;
    ??     out << s.l1;
           return out;       
        }
    };

    int main()
    { //test lijst template

    //example use of List<T>
        List<string> list2; 
        list2.add( "strand" );     
        list2.add( "zon" );     
        cout << list2; //print

        List<Second> l2;
        l2.add(Student("Jip");
    ??  l2.l1.add("name");

        return 0;
    }
```

I can make list for every type, every class. The problem is with l2 of type List, I want to access the l1 of type List in l2. I'm not able to access l1, I've tried alot with 'friend class' declarations and iterators.

For printing I get an error on out << s.l2 in the class Second, operator<<. 'Error: No match for operator<< in out << s.l2::l1'

I hope its clear enough, if not I'll edit in the Morning (CET). Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is `List`?  Why are you not using std::list (unless List is some sort of typedef of std::list<T>)?

Comment: `The problem is with l2 of type List, I want to access the l1 of type List in l2. I'm not able to access l1, I've tried alot with 'friend class' declarations and iterators`  So this "List" class is unit tested so well, and now you have problems with it.  How is that going to help us if the class you say has been tested really hasn't been tested?  We have no idea what it is, how it's implemented, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the confusement, the actual class called Lijst the Dutch word of list. In this code List is written with a capital to show its not std::list. 

The classes are tested, I can make Lists of every type. The trouble is with the access of the linked-list l1 in l2.


I'm creating a linked-list within a linked list, and want to access the class within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already has been said in the comments you should post the code for the `List` class template.

That being said my guess is as follows:

In your marked line `l2.l1.add("name");` you try to access the member `l1` of `l2` which is of type `List<Second>`.
Seeing that the wrapped class `Second` has a member `l1` I assume you actually want to access this member. 
This means you have to navigate to the data element you want to access first and then can operate on this data element.

Without giving your code for `List` we cannot say how to access the data element.

Comment: I'll try to find away around it. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Update: The List class I'm using seems incomplete, it is missing the operator []. Now its not possible to access the class List<First> l1. to get arround I'll use a std class like list or vector.

Comment: @jwrm22: You should always prefer the std containers if you have the choice between writing your own or using them. It is less coding and hence less possibility for errors.